# How can I prove this binomial probability question

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

[image]

I want to prove this question. But I am helpless. I don't have any clue how to solve this one. Can someone help

Comment: Consider the ratio of pmfs at successive integers $p(k+1)/p(k)$

Comment: Thanks I solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Work out the inequality $$p(k+1)>p(k)$$
All factors that both sides have in common (a lot) can be striped away.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem.

Comment: Nice to hear. You are welcome.